# select last user that changed an entity

Tags: sql, sql-server

From the table, I need to select the table which will contain only records with the user, DateTime and entity id 
with the latest user that changed a given entity 
MS SQL Server >= 2008

```
Input table: 

UserId, CreateDate, EntityID 
1 - 05.06.2000 - 1 
2 - 06.06.2000 - 1 
3 - 05.06.2000 - 2 


Output table: 

UserId, CreateDate, EntityID 
2 - 06.06.2000 - 1 
3 - 05.06.2000 - 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `row_number()` window function

```
select UserId,CreateDate,EntityID from
(select *,row_number()over(partition by UserId order by CreateDate desc) rn
from table
) a where a.rn=1
```